# Wordpress sitemap

Tags: wordpress, sitemap

Here my wordpress websites's sitemap:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}     (Googlebot|Bingbot|MSNbot|Webdup|AcoonBot|AhrefsBot|Ezooms|EdisterBot|EC2LinkFinder|jikespider|Purebot|MJ12bot|WangIDSpider|WBSearchBot|Wotbox|xbfMozilla|Yottaa|YandexBot|Jorgee|SWEBot|spbot|TurnitinBot-Agent|mail.RU|curl|perl|Python|Wget|Xenu|ZmEu) [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.suffolklawreviewab.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Someone could explain if a malware has write line 4 and 5? i've commented them prevently.

Another question:
Last two rewrite rules are made for indexing the sitemap?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you posted is not a sitemap, it is your htaccess file.

Regarding your first question, Yes that does look like a malware attack. Those two lines essentially say, if the user agent is google, bing, etc. then redirect to the URL in the second line. It's a way of hijacking search engine bots in order to have them index their site instead of yours. It can be difficult to detect this sort of attack because to a typical user everything appears normal.

Regarding your second question, it looks like those rules are meant to map sitemap requests back to your index file so whatever sitemap plugin you are using can serve the sitemap programatically rather than storing it in a static xml file. I would verify that this is in fact how your sitemap generator works given that your site has been compromised.

Also, just commenting those lines is not sufficient as a solution to your malware issue. It's likely that other aspects of your site have been compromised as well. My advice is:

- Change all of your passwords to prevent further attacks
- Use a scanning service such as sucuri.net to identify any additional issues and monitor for any future issues.
- Consider how your site became infected in the first place. Is your computer infected with malware? Are you storing your passwords securely? Same goes for anyone else who has access to your site.
- Once you have taken steps to verify that your site is clean, change your passwords again for good measure.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. Yes, i mispelled "htaccess", is that what i mean. Im using a famous plugin to manage my sitemap, so these lines seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes lines 4&5 are malware. That's going to redirect all search engines to their site, so they're essentially stealing all of your seo. The last two lines are not in itself malware, but you should check the sitemap and see what the sitemap says. Make sure you do a full hosting scan as somef ile is inserting these lines into your htaccess.